# Switching item viewtypes in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-recyclerview

My logic seems to be fine, but it just doesn't work.
I have 2 views A & B and I simply want to show B once after A has shown 5 times.
In my adapter

```
int itemCount = 0;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int pos){
    itemCount++;
    if(itemCount == 4){
        itemCount = 0;
        return VIEW_B;
    }else{
        return VIEW_A;
    }
}
```

I don't seem to know what's wrong. Any help would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `itemCount` variable; you should get rid of it. The Android system can (and will) call `getItemViewType()` repeatedly for the same positions and will call it with position arguments that aren't sequential. As such, you have to be able to return a value based solely on the `pos` argument to the method.

Try this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int pos){
    if((pos + 1) % 6 == 0){
        return VIEW_B;
    }else{
        return VIEW_A;
    }
}
```

Note that the `if` clause is not just `if (pos % 5 == 0)` since you said you didn't want to start with a "type a" view.

Comment: I don't totally understand your last statement "since you said you didn't want to start with a "type a" view"

Comment: If you use `if (pos % 5 == 0)` you'd see `B A A A A B A A A A B A A`. However, you said "I simply want to show B once after A has shown 5 times", so I assume you want to see `A A A A A B A A A A A B A` instead. That means you have to use `if((pos + 1) % 6 == 0){` instead.

Comment: Yeah it totally makes sense now. Because 0 % 5 = 0 hence the condition would hold true and return B.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you're adding the count to a global variable, and you're not guaranteed view type is sequential. Instead use
 `position % 5 == 0` 
for B otherwise A